# About the use of IncludeAction in struts

Tags: struts

I am just trying to use include action class in struts, but i am not able to do....the steps i did are as follows

step 1 : first I created the presentation page, which is

### Welcome.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean" prefix="bean"%>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Include Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div align="center">
        <bean:include id="bid" forward="logins" />      
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

step2: then I created servlet class, from where I passed msg in another client page

### ShowServlet.java

```
package com.ashish.struts.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.ashish.struts.LoginForm;

public class ShowServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws IOException,ServletException
    {
        System.out.println("Now I m in Servlet Class!!!!");
        String msg="This is your Login page";

        request.setAttribute("MSG", msg);

         RequestDispatcher rd= request.getRequestDispatcher("/index1.jsp");
         rd.forward(request, response);

    }
}
```

### index1.jsp

```
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Include Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div align="center">
            ${MSG }
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

step3: then finally i configured the struts-config.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 1.3//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-config_1_3.dtd">

<struts-config>
  <form-beans>
    <form-bean name="log" type="com.ashish.struts.LoginForm" />
  </form-beans>
  <global-exceptions />
  <global-forwards>
    <forward name="logins" path="/logs1.do" />
  </global-forwards>
  <action-mappings >
    <action path="/logs1" name="log" type="org.apache.struts.actions.IncludeAction" parameter="/WEB-INF/classes/com/ashish/struts/servlet/ShowServlet" />

  </action-mappings>
  <message-resources parameter="com.ashish.struts.ApplicationResources" />
</struts-config>
```

is there any things wrong i did , in the above steps or i left some things to do .....

because whenever i run this application , no error is showing , but desired output is not coming...

Can any one give the answer for that ...

Thanks 
Ashish....

Answer (score 3):

You have to add `<bean:write name="bid" />` in Welcome.jsp at the location where you want to display it.

Note: all `<bean:include id="NAME"... />` should have an accompanying `<bean:write name="NAME" />` to print the output message.